# How to set a empty path for the Binding in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, binding

I have a binding and i do not need a path. It works well if i set the ItemTemplate in xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="TestBindingPath.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ListView x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

But it throwed a Exception if i set the ItemTemplate in code

```
listview1.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding());
    return (new ViewCell() {
        View = label
    });
});
```

[image]
So how can i set a empty path for the Binding in code?

Comment: `new Binding("");` or `new Binding(".");`

Comment: Is this issue solved? If so, please post your answer. It will help others who have similar thread, thanks. And there is helpful article about binding.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings

Comment: Hi, new Binding("") is not working, but new Binding(".") works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the binding method structure.

```
 public Binding(string path, BindingMode mode = BindingMode.Default, IValueConverter converter = null, object converterParameter = null, string stringFormat = null, object source = null);
```

Try to do like this.

```
    listview1.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(source:Students));
    return (new ViewCell() {
        View = label
    });
});
```

Students property must be in the code bihind cs